# To use functions of common js library

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

In my laravel 5.6/jquery application I need to create some js file with common funcs and accessible in all js files of my project
and for this in app template
resources/views/cardsBS41Frontend/layouts/frontend.blade.php I added definition of js/app_funcs.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>@if(isset($site_name)){{ $site_name }}@endif</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/frontend.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->

    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}{{  "?dt=".time()  }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app_funcs.js') }}{{  "?dt=".time()  }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/bootstrap.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">

    <main class="py-4">
        @yield('content')
    </main>
</div>

@section('scripts')


@endsection

@yield('scripts')


</body>

@include($frontend_template_name.'.layouts.footer')
</html>
```

and in blade template resources/views/cardsBS41Frontend/vote.blade.php I attach /vote.js file, which refers only this template:

```
@extends($frontend_template_name.'.layouts.frontend')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
      ...CONTENT OF MY PAGE
    </div>


@endsection

@section('scripts')

            <script src="{{ asset('js/'.$frontend_template_name.'/vote.js') }}{{  "?dt=".time()  }}"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
                /*<![CDATA[*/

                var frontendVote = new frontendVote('view',  // must be called before jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                    <?php echo $appParamsForJSArray ?>
                );
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                    frontendVote.onFrontendPageInit('view')
                });

                /*]]>*/
            </script>

 @endsection
```

But in vote.js file when I call js function of js/app_funcs.js file I got error that

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: functionname is not defined
```

I expected to use of functions of js/app_funcs.js, as this file is attached and I see in console of the browser
that file js/app_funcs.js is retrieved ok BEFORE /vote.js.

Can you give me a hint what is wrong and which is the right way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the `app_funcs.js` script with `defer`. That means the script loads in parallel with the HTML but defers execution until the HTML is parsed. Since you're loading the `vote.js` script without `defer`, it stops HTML parsing, loading and executing immediately, effectively running it before the `app_funcs` script. Either defer the load of your `vote` script as well, or don't use `defer` with the `app_funcs` script.